# How do I write a regular expression that will match if the 6th character of a string is one of two different letters?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I'm trying to write a validator for an ASP.NET txtbox.

How can I validate so the regular expression will only match if the 6th character is a "C" or a "P"?

Comment: I don't know asp.net, isn't there a charAt method?

Answer (score 11):

`^.{5}[CP]` will match strings starting with any five characters and then a C or P.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on exactly what you want, you are looking for something like:

```
^.{5}[CP]
```

The `^` says to start from the beginning of the string, the `.` defines any character, the `{5}` says that the `.` must match 5 times, then the `[CP]` says the next character must be part of the **character class** `CP` - i.e. either a C or a P.

Comment: Updated with a slight correction taken from Carl's post - thanks @Carl!

Answer (score 2):

`^.{5}[CP]` -- the trick is the {}, they match a certain number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

`^.{5}[CP]` has a few important pieces:

- `^` = from the beginning
- `.` = match anything
- `{5}` = make the previous match the number of times in braces
- `[CP]` = match any one of the specific items in brackets

so the regex spoken would be something like "from the beginning of the string, match anything five times, then match a 'C' or 'P'"

Answer (score 0):

[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}[CP] will match any five characters or digits and then a C or P.

Comment: This will not work if the first 5 are not alpha-numeric. OP doesn't specify whether or not they are so don't assume they are.